# gulp 4 & babel 7 - Did you forget to signal async completion?

Tags: javascript, gulp, frontend, babeljs

I have a very simple gulpfile (cut this down to bare minimum repro case)...

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var log = require('fancy-log');

var scripts = {
    entry: 'temp/js/AppStart.js',
    tempIn: 'temp/js/**/*.js',
    tempOut: 'temp/js',
    dist: 'dist/js'
}

function babel() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        gulp.src(scripts.tempIn)
            .pipe(babel())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(scripts.tempOut))
            .on('end', resolve)
            .on('error', (error) => {
                log(error);
                reject()
            });
    });
}

gulp.task('js:babel', babel);
```

When I run `gulp js:babel` I get the following output...

```
PS D:\Projects\my-project\Front-End-build> gulp js:babel
[07:29:04] Using gulpfile D:\Projects\my-project\Front-End-build\gulpfile.js
[07:29:04] Starting 'js:babel'...
[07:29:04] The following tasks did not complete: js:babel
[07:29:04] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

How do I get this to run successfully?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply use return - always before gulp.src. And there is no need to wrap it in Promise, since gulp tasks are already async, only piped so executed one after another, but this will happen always unless you're using gulp.series()

Comment: is it ok to have 2 times babel? One as import and the other one as function name. It looks like a recursive task

Comment: @Zydnar I get the same error when just returning from gulp.src.

Comment: @Sodala well spotted. That was it. Thank-you. it's been driving me nuts!